# Python Remove two for loop and solve using some iterator tool

Tags: python, for-loop

I have  a dictionary

```
input = {
    1:[23,24],
    2:[21],
    3:[23],
    4:[]
    }
```

I want output like this:-

```
output = (1,23),(1,24),(2,21),(3,23)
```

I did this using two for loop:-

```
>>> for key in input:
...     for value in input[key]:
...         print """(""" + str(key) + """,""" +str(value) + """)"""
... 
(1,23)
(1,24)
(2,21)
(3,23)
```

can somebody tell me another approach ? Using some iterator tool or any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> [(key, value) for key, values in input.items() for value in values]
>>> [(1, 23), (1, 24), (2, 21), (3, 23)]
>>> '\n'.join('({},{})'.format(key, value) for key, values in input.items() for value in values)
'(1,23)\n(1, 24)\n(2, 21)\n(3, 23)'
>>> print('\n'.join('({},{})'.format(key, value) for key, values in input.items() for value in values))
(1,23)
(1,24)
(2,21)
(3,23)
>>> ','.join('({},{})'.format(key, value) for key, values in input.items() for value in values)
'(1,23),(1,24),(2,21),(3,23)'
```

Comment: Time complexity will not increase ??

Comment: @Anurag, O(len(key) + len(all values)). Space complexity is similar (result list).

Comment: @Anurag In other words, it's the same time complexity.

Comment: Hmm, I wanted to reduce the time complexity.

Comment: @Anurag: But you cannot get a complexity less than the size of the output list! If you want you can replace the `[]` with `()` and get a list generator that will create your tuples lazily.

Comment: @rodrigo `()` doesn't give you a list generator, but a generator expression as opposed to a list comprehension...

Answer (score 1):

Nice Question. Here is some pythonic solution. Expect some more pythonic solutions to come.

```
input = {
1:[23,24],
2:[21],
3:[23],
4:[]
}
def get_tuple(key,list):
    def map_key_value(element):
        return (key,element)
    return map(map_key_value,list)

def list_extend(elem1, elem2):
    elem1.extend(elem2)
    return elem1

print reduce(list_extend,map(get_tuple, input.keys(), input.values()))

>>> [(1, 23), (1, 24), (2, 21), (3, 23)]
```

Here is the short explanation:

map(get_tuple, input.keys(), input.values()) will return us the

**>>> [[(1, 23), (1, 24)], [(2, 21)], [(3, 23)], []]**

Basically we will get the list of lists. We then pass this list of lists to reduce, which gives us the single list, combining all into one.
Hence, we will get -

**>>> [(1, 23), (1, 24), (2, 21), (3, 23)].**